# Force download PDF from AWS S3 Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-disposition, force-download

I have access (paid for) to a pdf hosted on Amazon Web S3.  Access was granted via a pre-signed url.  The pdf opens in browser but I want to download it.

After reading around, it seems that this was due to the content-disposition header settings (server-side).

What can I do with the url, client side, to override the header or otherwise force the pdf to download?

Answer (score 1):

There is not anything that you can do, because of the way signed URLs work -- they are intrinsically tamper-resistant and essentially completely tamper-proof for all practical purposes.

Changing anything about a signed URL after it is signed invalidates the signature.

Disallowed changes include adding/removing/modifying the `response-content-disposition` query string parameter (which allows the `Content-Disposition` response header to be modified/overridden for that request).

Comment: Thank you Michael - that is a pity.  I thought there may be a way to do it by setting html download attribute but I could not get that to work.